# Происхождение слова «барабулька»

Tags: этимология

Какая этимология у слова «барабулька», это рыба такая. Позволю предположить, что оно связано с "булькать".

Comment: https://dzen.ru/a/YvoKgTNuwkohDjB9#:~:text=Название%20%23барабулька%20пришло%20в%20русский,необычные%20усы%2C%20достойные%20турецких%20султанов

Comment: @Sharon единственное, почему все эти источники постят "большая борода" так сложно забить в переводчик и понять что беюк - это усы, а борода - сакал. "Большие усы" - рыбка с большими усами.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[В русский язык название заимствовано через турецкое (barbunya) от итальянского barbone — большая борода, происходящего от латинского barbus — борода. С усами связано и второе имя рыбы — султанка, ибо такие роскошные усы могли быть только у повелителя мусульман.](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8#:%7E:text=%D0%92%20%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE,%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%20%D1%83%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%20%D0%BC%D1%83%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD.)